# Exercise 1.1c in Hartshorne's Deformation Theory: Is this family of conics flat?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, flatness, moduli-space, deformation-theory

In my attempt to solve Exercise 1.1c in Hartshorne's Deformation Theory book, which says that a family of conics in $\mathbb{P}^2$ parameterised by some finitely generated $k$-algebra $A$ ($k$ is algebraically closed of course, and let's say characteristic 0 for simplicity), say $X \subseteq \mathbb{P}^2_A$, flat over $A$, is defined by a single degree 2 polynomial. More precisely, the ideal in $A[x,y,z]$ corresponding to $X$ is principal, of degree 2.

There's a somewhat complicated story behind this question; in particular this [has been asked](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/292546/exercise-1-1-c-in-hartshornes-deformation-theory) on overflow, and the conclusion was that the question is wrong, and is only true **locally**. To me, that seems like it should be true for any finitely generated local $k$-algebra. However, I came up with the following example over $A = k[t]_{\langle t-1 \rangle}$; consider $$ \operatorname{Proj}A[x,y,z]/\langle tyz - x^2, yz - tx^2 \rangle.$$ Obviously the only closed fibre is $\operatorname{Proj} k[x,y,z]/yz = x^2$, but I am in the awkward situation of not being able to show that the ideal of the $X$ is principally generated, yet also not being able to show it is not flat. Indeed, one can show that $$(t+1)(yz-x^2) = 0$$ and since $t+1$ is invertible in $A$, it follows $yz-x^2 = 0$. However, I am not able to show that $tyz - x^2$ is in the ideal $\langle yz - x^2 \rangle$, and not able to find any torsion element either: obviously we have $$(t-1)(yz - x^2) = 0,$$ but as mentioned $yz-x^2$ is already zero, so this doesn't help!

And on that note, could I please have some hints on how to approach (the local version of) the exercise? Unfortunately the quoted overflow page only has the answer as to why it's **not** true, but nothing to show that it is true.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is pretty badly not flat. Over the generic point, the fiber of your subscheme is two fat points (your two quadrics intersect at $[0:0:1]$ and $[0:1:0]$ with common tangent line at each point). Over the special point, the fiber is one-dimensional. No jumping behavior like this can be flat.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not flat.

To see this we'll use the fact that over a local Noetherian domain, giving a flat family implies that the dimension of the fibers stays constant. Here, your ideal is $$ (tyz-x^2, yz-tx^2) = ((t^2-1)x^2, yz-tx^2) =  ((t-1)x^2, yz-tx^2) = ((t-1)x^2, yz-x^2) $$ So over the generic point, the ideal is given by $ (x^2, yz-x^2) = (x^2, yz) $, which is two non-reduced points, in particular, not of dimension 1, as the fiber over the closed point is.

Edit: I realized I typed this answer at the same time as KReiser's comment, which is the same thing.

Comment: No worries, it does occasionally happen that things are posted (relatively) simultaneously. +1 for taking the time to write it as an answer.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it.